# How to get attribute of webElement in nodejs after adding value in WebdriverIO nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

```
 String Style = driver.findElements(By.className("details")).get(numOfDay).getAttribute("style");
    if(!Style.contains("max-height:90x"))
    {
        Assert.fail(" hidden");
    }
```

Need to use above mentioned code in WebdriverIO nodejs
Can you please help to convert java to nodejs code

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
const allStyles = browser.elements('.details');
let style;
if(allStyles && allStyles.length && allStyles[numOfDay]){
    style = allStyles[numOfDay].getAttribute('style');
}

if(!style || !style.contains("max-height:90x"))
{
        Assert.fail(" hidden");
}
```